# Error: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'. But i see the logs in browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I got the error:

Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.
..... console.log(***blog.title***);

But at the console of Browser I am able to see the "blog.title".

[Here a screenshot from Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ15J.png)

In this file I use the console.log and recieve the error:

```
const BlogDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const {
    data: blog,
    error,
    isPending,
  } = useFetch("http://localhost:8500/blogs/" + id);

  console.log(blog&& blog.title);
  

  return (
    <div className="blog-details">
      {isPending && <div>loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      {blog && (
        <article>
          <h2>BlogDetails</h2>
        </article>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogDetails;
```

I use custom hook to fetch the Data:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    const useFetch = (url: string) => {
      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
      const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();
    
        setTimeout(() => {
          fetch(url, { signal: abortCont.signal })
            .then((res) => {
              if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error("could not fetch the data for that resource");
              }
              return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
              setIsPending(false);
              setData(data);
              setError(null);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              if (err.name === "AbortError") {
                console.log("fetch aborted");
              } else {
                setIsPending(false);
                setError(err.message);
              }
            });
        }, 1000);
        return () => abortCont.abort();
      }, [url]);
      return { data, isPending, error };
    };
    
    export default useFetch;
```

Comment: You initialize `data` and `error` with `null` so the compiler thinks these will always be `null`; if you have some wider type (e.g., `MyDataInterface | null` or `MyErrorType | null`) then you should specify that like `useState<MyDataInterface | null>(null)` so the compiler knows what's happening.  See the answer to the linked question for more info.

Comment: @jcalz - although the question you've linked would solve this specific problem, it doesn't take into account the generic nature of `useFetch` as a custom hook. As the soon as the user would fetch another type of data, he'll need to change `useFetch` as well.

Comment: @OriDrori Is there some criterion other than "solve this specific problem" we should be using here?  I'm happy to vote to reopen if you think the scope of the question is wider.

Comment: @jcalz The difference is - solve this specific use of `useFetch` vs. allow `useFetch` to be used with any api call. The question is wider since `useFetch` can be used with multiple data types. I suggest reopening it.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for ur reply. 
 
The data Object look like this: 
'{
  "blogs": [
    {
      "title": "my new Website",
      "body": "lorem ipsum...",
      "author": "Mozo",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Welcome Party",
      "body": "lorem ipsum...",
      "author": "mozamel",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
};'



I used like the following but it does not work: 

`type prop = {
  blogs: {
    title: string;
    body: string;
    author: string;
    id: number;
  }[];
};`

'const [data, setData] = useState<{ prop: null | string }>({ prop: null });'

Answer (score 3):

Typescript can't infer the types from an api call, so you'll need to provide them explicitly.

However, since `useFetch` is a generic function, you'll need to add a type that fits the call, and pass it to the internal `useState`. In addition, the initial value of `useState` is `null`, so we should also consider that.

We can add a generic type to `useFetch` - `<T>`, and type `useState<T | null>()` to allow for the intended data type, and `null`:

```
export const useFetch = <T>(url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
```

To use it, you'll need to pass an explicit type to `useFetch`. For example:

```
interface Data { 
  title: string;
  body: string;
  author: string;
  id: number;
}

const { data: blog, error, isPending } = useFetch<Data>(
  'http://localhost:8500/blogs/' + id
);

console.log(blog && blog.title); // or just console.log(blog?.title) with optional chaining
```

Whenever you call `useFetch` you should provide it with the data type that fits the current response. For example:

```
useFetch<string[]>( // the result is an array of strings

useFetch<Data[]>( // the result is an array of data objects

useFetch<number>( // the result is a number
```

Comment: Tanx, It worked. 
But now i recieve an Error in other file, in which i am using the useFetch file. 
Here is the code in this file: 

`interface Data {
  title: string;
}
const Home = () => {
  const {
    data: blogs,
    isPending,
    error,
  } = useFetch<Data>(" http://localhost:8500/blogs");

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs!" />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
`

Comment: TS2740: Type 'Data' is missing the following properties from type '{ title: string; body: string; author: string; id: number; }[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
    17 |       {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
    18 |       {error && <div>{error}</div>}
  > 19 |       {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs!" />}
       |                           ^^^^^
    20 |     </div>
    21 |   );
    22 | };

Comment: '
type prop = {
  blogs: {
    title: string;
    body: string;
    author: string;
    id: number;
  }[];
  title: string;
};

const BlogList = (blogs: prop) => {
  return (
    <div className="blog-list">
      <h2>{blogs.title}</h2>
      {blogs.blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
          <Link to={`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>
            <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
            <p>Written by {blog.author}</p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogList;
'

Comment: If you are expecting an array of data objects, you should call `useFetch` like this `useFetch<Data[]>(`.

Comment: Thank u, But the Error is not depend of that: 
I have an error in the following line: 
 {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs!" />}

I will post the BlogList file in the next comment.

Comment: `type prop = {
  blogs: {
    title: string;
    body: string;
    author: string;
    id: number;
  }[];
  title?: string;
};

const BlogList = (blogs: prop) => {
  return (
    <div className="blog-list">
      <h2>{blogs.title}</h2>
      {blogs.blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
          <Link to={`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>
            <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
            <p>Written by {blog.author}</p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};`

Comment: I see the problem, and it's what I told you exactly. You need to call `useFetch` with the type of the data you are expecting. If you do `useFetch<Data>`, the type of data won't be the one for blogs, because blogs return `{ title: string, blogs: Data[] }`, so you need to create another type `interface Blogs { title: string, blogs: Data[] }`m and call `useFetch<Blogs>(`.

Comment: And you should also pass `Blogs` as the props type to the BlogList - `const BlogList = (props: Blogs) => `.

Comment: Tanx once again. I have the same problem like before: 

`interface Data {
  title: string;
}
interface Blogs {
  title: string;
  blogs: Data[];
}

const Home = () => {
  const {
    data: blogs,
    isPending,
    error,
  } = useFetch<Blogs[]>(" http://localhost:8500/blogs");
  console.log(blogs);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs!" />}
    </div>
  );
};`

Comment: You should use - `useFetch<Blogs>`. You and type the components accordingly. It won't work if things don't match. Read some tutorials about using React and typescript.